# Xp repair won't start setup wizard

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, bsod

I ran a repair on my xp system and it will not get to the xp setup wizard.  I have important data that is intact on the system so I do not want to format it if I can help it.  Here is what iplan to do, but would like some feedback before I adventure down this road:

I'm thinking of backing up the registry via erd commander and copying the entire C: drive to a removable device.  From there I will take a fresh copy of windows xp, restore the registry from the dead comp, and then overwrite the entire C: drive with the contents of the dead comps C: drive.  In theory would this allow me to run all the programs and use the data by transferring it this way?

Thanks,
Msindle

Comment: What error comes up when you try running the setup? We need more info

Comment: I see you have tagged 'bsod'.. Do you get a Blue Screen of Death? If 'yes' can you upload the minidump please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to copy all your programs, files, and settings to a new computer (different from your old one) by backing up the registry, installing Windows XP on the new computer, restoring the registry to the computer, and then restoring a clone of the old hard drive to the new computer.  This won't work for several reasons.

- Backing and restoring the registry and reinstalling XP is redundant because if you're going to restore a clone of the hard drive, the registry and XP are already included in the image to be restored.
- Restoring a clone of your old hard drive to a computer with new hardware isn't recommended because it probably won't work.

If that's what you're trying to do, it probably won't work.  However, if you're just replacing a dead hard drive, cloning the old drive and restoring to the new will probably work.

Comment: I'm trying to do the method that wont work...i'm just grasping for straws at this point in time.